# I just want to validate whether entering serial_no is existing in database or not, My AsynTask is not working after i modified code like this.

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

I want to check whether the serial_no is already existing or not in my table , But always throughback me this "Check Your Internet. Make sure you turn on the Internet or WIFI" Toast massage, Following are my async code

```
    class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(EnterDetailes.this, "",
                "Submitting. Please wait...", true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String imagename=getStringImage(bitmap);


        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String result;

        try
        {
            data = "?ImageName="+imagename.replace(" ","%20");
            data += "&district="+District.replace(" ","%20");
            data += "&gender="+Gender.replace(" ","%20");
            data += "&city="+City.replace(" ","%20");
            data += "&serialno="+SerialNo.replace(" ","%20");
            // data += "&area="+Area.replace(" ","%20");
            data += "&agencyid="+ID.replace(" ","%20");
            data += "&wareno="+WareNo.replace(" ","%20");
            data += "&latitude="+Latitude.replace(" ","%20");
            data += "&longitude="+Longitude.replace(" ","%20");

            link = "http://www.lorryguru.com/domag/submitdog.php" + data;
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
            return query_result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "No Internet";
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        dialog.hide();

        if(s.equals("Success"))
        {
            s="Uploaded Successfully.";
            serialno.setText("");
            wareno.setText("");
            textViewGpsLat.setText("");
            textViewGpsLng.setText("");
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
        else if(s.equals("Already Exists"))
        {
            s="Sorry, serial number already exists";
        }
        else if(s.equals("Fail"))
        {
            s="Sorry, Some query error";
        }
        else
        {
            s="Check Your Internet. Make sure you turn on the Internet or WIFI";
        }
        Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My PHP code is this

```
       <?php
       require 'init.php';
       date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
       $date    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

       $serialno = $_REQUEST["serialno"];

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM dogs_details WHERE serial_no='".$serialno."' ";
       $res = $db->prepare($sql);
       $res->execute();
       $count =  $res->rowCount();
       if($count>0)
       {
       echo '{"query_result":"Already Exists"}';    
       }
       else{


      $district     = $_REQUEST["district"];
      $city         = $_REQUEST["city"];
      $gender   = $_REQUEST["gender"];
      $serialno     = $_REQUEST["serialno"];
      $agency_id    = $_REQUEST["agencyid"];
      $wareno   = $_REQUEST["wareno"];
      $before   = $_REQUEST["ImageName"];
      $latitude     = $_REQUEST["latitude"];
      $longitude    = $_REQUEST["longitude"];
      $path         = "before_dog/".uniqid().".jpg";
      $actualpath = "http://www.lorryguru.com/domains/dogs/$path";

      $db->beginTransaction();
      $query    = $db->prepare("insert into dogs_details(district,city,gender,serial_no,ware_no,latitude,longitude,posted_on,before_dog,agency_id) VALUES ( ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $query->bindValue(1, $district );
    $query->bindValue(2, $city);
    $query->bindValue(3, $gender);
    $query->bindValue(4, $serialno);
    $query->bindValue(5, $wareno);
    $query->bindValue(6, $latitude);
    $query->bindValue(7, $longitude);
    $query->bindValue(8, $date);
    $query->bindValue(9, $actualpath);
    $query->bindValue(10, $agency_id);



    try{
        $query->execute();
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($before));
        $db->commit();
        echo '{"query_result":"Success"}';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
        $db->rollBack();
        echo '{"query_result":"Fail"}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Debug and check what value of 's' you are getting.